# How can I make different scroll shape for collectionviewcells in the same CollectionViewController

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am using 3 different CollectionViewCells in UICollectionViewController. I don't want any scroll feature for the 1st cell. I want the 2nd cell to move horizontally. For the 3rd cell I want it to move vertically. there is no such feature in the .xib file of the cells.

How can I do it with code?

Thank you.